# Querying database for slug match?

Tags: slug

Does anyone know how to query the database to find entry data based on a slug? The only table field I see that contains slug data is in craft_entryversions.data  in json format. Anyone ever tried querying for matches?

Comment: Does it need to be a SQL query or are you open to using the built in Craft API?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `craft_elements_i18n` table?

Comment: @Aaron: I have an array of slugs that I want to query for. I'm open to the API but I'm sort of new to plugin development. Not sure where to start. I imagine the API method would be better for getting images and such. If you can point me to the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about querying using SQL directly, then the `craft_elements_i18n` table is where all of the slugs are kept.

Comment: Yeah I ended up bumping into that table and I see elementId is the entry id. Getting image data gets tricky I guess.